# Portable class library in visual studio 2013 (wp7/win8)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library, visual-studio-2013

[image: image 1]

How to create PCL wp7/win8 in visual studio 2013?
I have already installed windows phone 7 sdk and windows phone 8 sdk, but it does not help.
There is no option for wp 7.1.

Comment: Phones don't live that long.  After the typical one or two year phone company contract is up, everybody moves to the next version.  I'd readily assume that 7.1 won't be back.

Comment: The above point is irrelevant. Windows Phone 8 and 8.1 are fully backwards compatible, and therefore it's still viable to target Windows Phone 7(.1) (which ensures an app will work on all versions from WP7 up to WP8.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that VS 2013 is still a preview. So maybe it will be available later but for the moment it looks like you can only create a PCL project with support for both Windows Phone 7 and Windows Store apps by using Visual Studio 2012

[image: PCL Library / Windows Phone 7.1 and Windows Store apps (Windows 8)]

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio does not support Windows Phone 7 development.

This may change in the future but, based on what has happened with previous versions of Visual Studio and separate SDKs,  I suspect that is unlikely.

It's only possible to target PCL projects for SDKs that are installed.

You could build your PCL in VS2012 and consume it in a VS2103 project though.

On the other (/plus?) side, there are free versions of VS2012 and VS2013 and the can be installed side by side so you'll be able to build for WP7 for plenty of time to come.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2013 has removed support for Windows Phone 7.x, Silverlight 4 and Xbox development.

For the entire list of compatibility between Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747(v=vs.120).aspx.

Comment: you could install the Visual Studio 2012 Express edition (or a full one if you have say MSDN subscription or already own it) side by side with VS2013. The latest update for VS2012 can open the solution/project format of VS2013 and the same is true for VS2010. So you could have a PCL (with WP7 target) and WP7 project too in a solution and Visual Studio 2013 will just skip them (not load those projects). Also there is possibility you could add targeting packs for VS2013 that allow the WP7 target for PCLs (maybe someone could grab such targeting pack from VS2012 somehow and adapt to VS2013)

Comment: ...also see my reply with a way to edit the profiles that describe those platforms to allow them to be used at newer Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution according to
http://www.johanlaanstra.nl/2013/09/22/portable-class-libraries-with-wp7-support-in-visual-studio-2013-rc

> ...was wondering why Visual Studio would upgrade the project while the
>   profile was there on disk. While digging through the xml files for
>   Profile104 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile104),
>   which is the profile I was using, I found some xml files in the
>   SupportedFrameworks subfolder. These xml files defined a
>   MinimumVisualStudioVersion and a MaximumVisualStudioVersion. For
>   Profile104, one of the files contained MaximumVisualStudioVersion="11"
>   which means Visual Studio 2012. Changing all xml files for the profile
>   to have MaximumVisualStudioVersion="12", which means Visual Studio
>   2013, made my scenario work after a restart of Visual Studio. I can
>   now open the PCL in Visual Studio 2013 without it being upgraded. Make
>   sure you restart VS after this change to make it work.